# Does the space of Slater determinants or bosonic permanents have any nice mathematical structure?

Tags: hilbert-space, variational-principle, mathematics, many-body

(This is a soft question.)

In the Hartree-Fock approximation, you approximate the ground state of a many-body fermionic system by performing a variational minimization of the expected energy of a given interacting Hamiltonian over the space of non-interacting Slater determinants, instead over the full many-body fermionic Hilbert space. (Minimizing over the full Hilbert space would give you the exact ground state by the variational principle, but it is usually intractably large. The set of Slater determinants is a much smaller subset of the full Hilbert space, so this approximation is often more tractable.)

Unlike the full Hilbert space, the space of Slater determinants is not closed under linear combinations (that's the whole point, since it makes the set much smaller!), so it is not a vector space. As such, much of the nice mathematical structure of Hilbert spaces is immediately lost. Nor is it a convex set. In general, does it have any "nice, natural" mathematical structure at all that we can use (e.g. topological, smooth, differentiable, algebraic, or category-theoretic structure)? Or can we not say much more beyond that it's a subset of a Hilbert space? (I guess it inherits a natural metric from the Hilbert space, so it's at least a metric space?)

The same question applies to the space of bosonic permanents, although these are less useful in practice, because the permanent is so much harder to compute numerically and because many-boson systems occur less often in nature than many-fermion electronic systems.